# SSH using python script

Tags: linux, python-3.x, unix

I want to SSH using a user and password. The format of SSH that works is :-

ssh admin@IP
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Password:

And the password is required.. so how should i design the script so that it could take user Input as the IP.?

Comment: There's no reason to use the external ssh command when native-Python SSH libraries exist (and give you full control over the process, including authentication); see f/e [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/).

Comment: Beyond that, this doesn't tell us what you tried, and doesn't tell us what specific problem you encountered. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this will help you achieve what you are looking for using Paramiko.

```
import paramiko
import time

ip = input("Please enter IP")
name = input("Please enter UserName")
password = input("Please enter Password")
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname=ip,username=name,password=password)   #This is used to establish a connection

remote_connection = ssh_client.invoke_shell() #This helps you invoke the shell of the client machine

remote_connection.send("cli\n")           #These commands are used to send command over
remote_connection.send("configure\n")     #to the remote machine that you are trying to connect with


time.sleep(5) 
output = remote_connection.recv(10240)  #This is to recieve any output that you get on the after SSH
                                        #connection is established

ssh_client.close                        #This closes your active SSH connection
```

For official documentation please read [here](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/).

Answer (score 2):

Do `pip install fabric`

See [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)

**Example**

```
from fabric import Connection
result = Connection('web1.example.com').run('uname -s', hide=True)
msg = "Ran {0.command!r} on {0.connection.host}, got stdout:\n{0.stdout}"
print(msg.format(result))
```